# VB.Net REGEX to strip email

Tags: regex, vb.net, email

I have a need to strip email addresses out of paragraphs of plain text. I have googled and search this site and found many suggestions - none of which I can get to work. I'm using code like this:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

        Dim strEmailPattern As String = "^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$"       
        Dim senText As String = "blah blah blah blah blah someone@somewhere.com"  
        Dim newText As String = String.Empty

        newText = Regex.Replace(senText, strEmailPattern, String.Empty)
```

After the call to Regex.Replace the newText string still contains the complete senText string including the email. I thought it was the regex pattern I was using but I have tried many so maybe I'm am missing something in the code?

Comment: Best regex to find emails from text data is `(\w[\w.-]+@)+\w[\w.-]+`. Beside this there is no way to parse emails.

Comment: This worked !!! - If you post it as a reply instead of a comment I wwill mark it as the answer

Comment: an email address doesnt always have a word..it can have almost anything..that regex would break

Comment: @JimEvans I have added an answer already. and that contains more proper regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This posix regex should match all the emails, provided

1. they may not be valid
2. every email contains at least on `@`
3. there are sequences of characters around `@` symbols which includes alphabet, digits, hyphen and dots and not started by any non-alpha characters.
4. All emails are separated by at least a single space char.

Regex

```
([[:alpha:]][[:alnum:].-]+@)+[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:].-]+
```

This might also work

```
([a-zA-Z][[a-zA-Z0-9].-]+@)+[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.-]+
```

A shorter version (as in comment) would be

```
(\w[\w.-]+@)+\w[\w.-]+
```

But this will match some more invalid emails.

The patter I am addressing will match most of the email addresses. if you really want to match all the RFC-822 compliant emails, consider using the [pattern here](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html). Its a 6425 character long regex  that matches all the standard email address. But be ware, it'll execute slow!

Comment: this is not right..email address can contain almost [anything](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local_part) ..that would break the code

Comment: Yes. I know email address can contain anything. Thats why I added **provided** assumptions.

Comment: `~$%%.a"@example.org` is also a valid email address

Comment: According to my assumptions for this answer `~$%%.a"@example.org` will not be used here. I know I didn't provided the *perfect* answer

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ, `abc@efg.hij@klm.nop` is a valid email too.

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ It wont fail on **most** of the email addresses. Rather it'll be **lest** of the email which will be failed.

Comment: OK - just to get it straight - this is the only one that has workd for me at all - (\w[\w.-]+@)+\w[\w.-]+ So shiplu.mokadd.im entered that in a comment above and that is what I wish to make the correct answer to my issue.

Comment: @Jim that pattern will match `abc@gmail_com.net`. `_` is not a valid char for domain. So I changed it

Comment: @JimEvans added that pattern on my answer.

Answer (score -1):

There are various corner cases where your regex would fail..

you should use as simple as this

`(?<=^|\s)[^@]+?\@[^@]+?(?=$|\s)`

Comment: Your regex pattern fails at "one two John Smith <info@foo.com> three four five" since it matches "one two John Smith <info@foo.com>" as a valid email address